# Возможно ли записывать и читать из одного экземпляра Stream?

Tags: c#, потоки-данных

Мне не хватает фундаментального понимания такой штуки, как Stream. Фраза "абстракция над последовательностью байтов", которую встречаю везде, не спасает.

Как известно, ничто не мешает написать что-то вроде этого:

```
var fs = File.Open("file.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
var sr = new StreamReader(fs);
```

Здесь и пишущему, и читающему Stream'ам присваивается один и тот же экземпляр базового (не в смысле ооп, просто как поле). Несмотря на то, что они будут вести свои счетчики передвижения по файлу, свои буферы, интуитивно понятно, что можно записывать в один и тот же файл (=базовый Stream) и читать из него условно в один момент времени, ничего в этом такого нет.

А что представляет собой Stream применительно к сетевому взаимодействию?

У меня возникла задача удаленно, через SSH, взаимодействовать с shell лунукса. Насколько правильно (неправильно) и для передачи данных, и для их чтения с сервера использовать один и тот же экземпляр Stream (как в случае с файлом)?

В случае, если Stream представляет собой только пришедшие с сервера байты, то нет смысла туда что-то еще писать. А если это "канал", поток байтов клиент-сервер, то есть смысл. Или все зависит от конкретной реализации наследника класса Stream?

Словом, немного запутался.

Comment: У класса `Stream` есть [свойства](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3) `CanRead`, `CanSeek`, `CanWrite` - именно они дают понять, можно ли читать-писать в поток (одновременно или нет - не суть).

Answer (score 1):

> Фраза "абстракция над последовательностью байтов", которую встречаю везде, не спасает.

И тем не менее именно эта фраза и должна спасать :) Возможно, [цитата с MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.stream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) привнесёт больше ясности:

> Предоставляет универсальное представление последовательности байтов. Этот класс является абстрактным.

То есть, Stream - это [абстрактный класс](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/sf985hc5.aspx), представляющий **последовательность байтов** (да, я просто переставил слова в предыдущей цитате). То есть, в вашем случае - это последовательность пришедших с сервера байтов.

**Update**

Входящий поток - это набор данных, пришедших с сервера. Вот, грубо (очень грубо) говоря, вы скачиваете файл потоком. Вы можете писать в этот поток - но вы будете писать в скачиваемый файл, на сервере этот файл останется неизменным. Точно так же вы можете писать в локальный файл. Просто в случае потока, получаемого с сервера, вы пишете **в свой экземпляр** файла. Но вы же можете отправить исходящий поток, и таким образом организовать канал самостоятельно.

Comment: Думаю, вы неправильно поняли. Я вполне осознал, что class Stream - это абстрактный класс для его реализации конкретными наследниками. Мой вопрос касался того, **какие именно** байты представляет **не** абстрактная реализация Stream. Если, как вы пишите, я читаю лишь ответ от сервера, то я не могу одновременно записывать в тот же экземпляр, это не имеет смысла. А если наш Stream - это двухсторонний канал, представляет собой байты и клиента, и сервера? Такое возможно? Вот в случае с файлом на локальной машине, да. А в сети?

Comment: @Mergasov Сделал апдейт в ответе

Answer (score 1):

Применительно к сетевому взаимодействию - `NetworkStream` - это обертка над сокетом. Все, что пишется в `NetworkStream` - уходит на сервер. То, что прислал сервер - можно прочитать из того же экземпляра `NetworkStream`.

> Насколько правильно (неправильно) и для передачи данных, и для их чтения с сервера использовать один и тот же экземпляр Stream (как в случае с файлом)?

Это нормально, и именно так и задумано. И `NetworkStream`, и лежащие под ними сокеты - это двунаправленные каналы.